# How to pass url as url parameter in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to pass url as parameter for another url. For example

https://www.host1.com?returnURL=https://www.host2.com/path?queryparamater1=value&queryparameter2=value

```
var returnUrlComponents = URLComponents()
        returnUrlComponents.scheme = "https"
        returnUrlComponents.host = "www.host.com"
        returnUrlComponents.path = "/path1"
        let queryItem1 = URLQueryItem(name: "param1", value: "value1")
        let queryItem2 = URLQueryItem(name: "redirect_uri", value: "test://result")
        returnUrlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem1, queryItem2]
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()

        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "www.anotherhost.com"
        urlComponents.path = "/path2"
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "returnURL", value: returnUrlComponents.url?.absoluteString)]
        print(urlComponents.url?.absoluteString)
```

The output is this - https://www.anotherhost.com/path2?returnURL=https://www.host.com/path1?param1%3Dvalue1%26redirect_uri%3Dtest://result

Expected output - https://www.anotherhost.com/path2?returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.host.com%2Fpath1%3Fparam1%3Dvalue1%26redirect_uri%3Dtest%3A%2F%2Fresult

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a that specific URL pattern, you might have to build the string yourself.  If you're ok with URL encoding the parameters, you can use `addingPercentEncoding` with `urlHostAllowed` as the encoding.

```
var returnUrlComponents = URLComponents()
returnUrlComponents.scheme = "https"
returnUrlComponents.host = "www.host.com"
returnUrlComponents.path = "/path1"
let queryItem1 = URLQueryItem(name: "param1", value: "value1")
let queryItem2 = URLQueryItem(name: "redirect_uri", value: "test://result")
returnUrlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem1, queryItem2]

var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "https"
urlComponents.host = "www.anotherhost.com"
urlComponents.path = "/path2"

let encodedReturnUrlComponents = returnUrlComponents.url?.absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "returnURL", value: encodedReturnUrlComponents)]

print(urlComponents.url?.absoluteString)
```

That output would be `https://www.anotherhost.com/path2?returnURL=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.host.com%252Fpath1%253Fparam1%3Dvalue1%26redirect_uri%3Dtest%253A%252F%252Fresult`

Just a heads up though, since its a query param, the encoding will be double encoded.  For instance, %253A will be used instead of %3A (which in the end represents ":").

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried this approach but it is double encoded. Finally I built the string myself. Not the clean and good way but it works. Will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output by building the url itself. Not the clean and good code but it works.

```
var returnUrlComponents = URLComponents()
        returnUrlComponents.scheme = "https"
        returnUrlComponents.host = "www.host.com"
        returnUrlComponents.path = "/path1"
        let queryItem1 = URLQueryItem(name: "param1", value: "value1")
        let queryItem2 = URLQueryItem(name: "returnURI", value: "test://result")
        returnUrlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem1, queryItem2]
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()

        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "www.anotherhost.com"
        urlComponents.path = "/path2"

        let unreservedCharset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-._~" )
        var allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
        allowedCharacterSet.formUnion(unreservedCharset)

        var urlString = urlComponents.url?.absoluteString
        urlString?.append("?returnURL=")
        if let encodedURLString = returnUrlComponents.url?.absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) {
            urlString?.append(encodedURLString)
        }
//This step is not necessary. urlString can be printed directly.
        if let urlStr = urlString, let urlComp = URLComponents(string: urlStr) {
            urlComponents = urlComp
        }
        print(urlComponents.url?.absoluteString)
```